# What should winapi signal handler return?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, signals

In [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/signal?view=msvc-170), the windows c runtime library function:
`void __cdecl *signal(int sig, int (*func)(int, int));` is defined to take a signal handler `func` which returns an `int`.

I couldn't find in the very documentation, an explanation of what this int should be.

Comment: Because i am writing a c++ code. and still using this function

Comment: note that in the example down on same page the signalHandler is `void (int)`, though I don't know C, so I have no clue how that works

Comment: Is there a cpp specific function for signal handling?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number confusing, right? =)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I quite like your proposition to use std. You can write it has an answer maybe ;)

Comment: it does not answer the question you asked. For the question you did ask I suggest to remove the C++ tag. And for the question you wanted to ask ("how to use signalhandler in C++?"), I also cannot tell you anything that you cannot find on the cppref site

Comment: for c++, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/signal. Here, the definition of the function is "void (*) (int)" as in the example of windows documention.

Comment: You should not be using signals altogether on Windows. The implementations are provided solely to make porting POSIX applications easier. If you aren't porting a POSIX application, use a system service that's better suited to the problem at hand. Incidentally, what is that problem?

Comment: @IInspectable I have an asynch logger and i was trying to catch all unexpected shutdown to be able to always flush before shutdown. I use a combination of atexit, signal, and SetUnhandledExceptionFilter. I ain't sure it is the proper way to do it. I am just mimicking code around me. Very curious to know if you recommand something else.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea to want to try to flush application state after the application has (potentially) entered an unreliable state. What *I* would do instead is to set up Windows Error Reporting to produce crash dumps on unhandled exceptions, and switch to a logging infrastructure that doesn't required flushing (e.g. Event Tracing for Windows, ETW).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for the tip, i will google that

Comment: I'd say it is a typo in the documentation: In [signal.h](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.16299.0/ucrt/signal.h#L19) it is shown as return `void` and taking only one argument. The example in your doc also shows `void (*)(int)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the definition of `signal` in the linked documentation:

```
void __cdecl *signal(int sig, int (*func)(int, int));
```

But `signal` is defined as a standard library C function (aligned with the POSIX standard but that is besides the point in Windows), so if the MS documentation fails, the next best thing is the C standard.

Looking at the C specification, `signal` is, quite confusingly, defined as:

```
#include <signal.h>
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

Looking at the VisualStudio C header file `signal.h` (removing some MS-ism macros for clarity), the definition is clearer with the help of a typedef for the function pointer type, but equivalent:

```
typedef void (* _crt_signal_t)(int);
_crt_signal_t __cdecl signal(int _Signal, _crt_signal_t _Function);
```

Note that the `_crt_signal_t` typedef is internal and undocumented. It should not be used in portable code.

So the documentation is wrong: there is only one `int` argument to the signal callback and it should return `void`.

Curiously, the example in the linked documentation gets it right:

```
void SignalHandler(int signal) { /* ... */ }

int main()
{
    typedef void (*SignalHandlerPointer)(int);

    SignalHandlerPointer previousHandler;
    previousHandler = signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);
    /* ... */
}
```